# How can I create a Grey swatch using the swatch palette?

Tags: adobe-indesign, swatches

I realize this is a super stupid question but I do not know how to create a grey color with the swatch palette. Here is what my current setup is. Isn't there some color scale that is strictly greyscale where you can select something between black and white?

Here is what I am currently working with in terms of options:

[image]

Comment: Do you want pure grey or an RGB grey?? Setting all the RGB colors to the same number will equal a grey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a grey value in RGB, you need to set all 3 colors the same. So R195 G195 B195 is a grey. Higher numbers mean a lighter grey, lower numbers are darker.

In addition, you can also simply use the **tint** slider on the **Color Panel** after clicking the "Black" swatch. This will yield greys as well. You can also drag those tints from the **Color Panel** to the **Swatch Panel** to reuse them.